# Turning byte array into Bitmap

Tags: java, android, c++, image, bitmap

I have a server in cpp and a client in Java where I am sending an image from the server to the client in segments.  On the client side I pick up all the segment to form a single array of bytes.

My problem is that I don't seem to be able to successfully create a bitmap out of this byte array, since I get null using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`

Client code:

```
byte[] response_bytes;
private Bitmap receive_image ( final String protocol, final int image_size, final int buffer_size)
{
    if (image_size <= 0 || buffer_size <= 0)
        return null;

    Thread image_receiver = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(image_size);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
            int bytesReadSum = 0;
            try {
                while (bytesReadSum != image_size) {
                    activeReader.read(buffer);
                    String message = new String(buffer);
                    if (TextUtils.substring(message, 0, len_of_protocol_number).equals(protocol)) {
                        int bytesToRead = Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.substring(message, 
                                len_of_protocol_number, 
                                len_of_protocol_number + len_of_data_len));

                        byteBuffer.put(Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 
                                len_of_protocol_number + len_of_data_len, 
                                bytesToRead + len_of_protocol_number + len_of_data_len));
                        bytesReadSum += bytesToRead;
                    } else {
                        response_bytes = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (bytesReadSum == image_size) {
                    byte[] image_bytes = byteBuffer.array();
                    if (image_bytes.length > 0)
                        response_bytes = image_bytes;
                    else
                        response_bytes = null;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                response_bytes = null;
            }
        }
    });
    image_receiver.start();
    try {
        image_receiver.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        response_bytes = null;
    }

    if (response_bytes != null) {    //Here image_bitmap is null
        Bitmap image_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(response_bytes, 0, response_bytes.length);
        return image_bitmap;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

At this point I'd also like to mention that the image bytes reading seems to work fine and I manage to read all the bytes of the image without fail.
Yet, I'm unable to turn that array of bytes into a bitmap.

Comment: one thing you might want to sort out first is whether a) response_byte is corrupted or b) the image is not a supported format. try to put a breakpoint or a log just before decodebytearray and see if response_bytes is not null or something

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The image is in JPG format. I have checked already and response_bytes contains the right amount of bytes just before I call decodeByteArray.

Comment: i think the bytes are corrupted, the way they are retrieved is very confusing

Comment: Haven't done Java for a while, but If I'm remembering correctly, and apologies if I'm conflating with C and C++, you've ignored the return value of  `activeReader.read(buffer);`which should contain a number between 0 and the length of `buffer`. I do not believe there is a guarantee that you get a full buffer.

Comment: And why flip back and forth with a String? There could be encoding conversions in there that eat your raw binary representation.

Comment: I must admit that you're somewhat correct, as this code is a little confusing. As part of the communication protocol, the first 12 bytes are not added into the image bytes since they represent information related to the data - the first 5 bytes are the protocol and the followong 7 bytes respresent the size of the data. I'll check again if there's a corruption in the data, though I believe it's not the problem, thanks!

Comment: user4581301, I'm creating a string that contains that bytes, leaving the original array of bytes unchanged. I do that in order to tread the first 12 bytes of readable information.

Comment: What is the size of the jpg file? And its resolution?

Comment: Save the received bytes to file instead of making a bitmap out of it.

Comment: size: 108 KB (110,603 bytes)
resolution: 720:1280

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: And how many bytes did you receive?

Comment: I've sent 110603 bytes and received the same amount